# Is any special information (like the previous command) available to PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm interested in getting the just-run command in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, is there any better way of doing so beyond `history 1`?

More generally, what information is available at the time `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed? I know that `$?` is the exit code of the just-run command, but I'm not sure what else is available.

Comment: everything what available in bash

Comment: `!!` or `!-1` - refer to the `Event Designators` subsection under the `HISTORY EXPANSION` section of the bash manual

Comment: @IporSircer that isn't the question. I realize `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a Bash expression. The question is about the context the expression is evaluated in.

Comment: You can find out what's available with `PROMPT_COMMAND="set >/tmp/prompt_command.log"`.

Comment: @MateiDavid good idea thanks. I posted an answer with the result of running `set` from `PROMPT_COMMAND`, and it indicates there are no environment variables being set.

Comment: Not sure what you are after, but there's a whole mass of pre-defined bash internal variables described in the man page under "Shell Variables".

Comment: @meuh I'm after any special values or state made available specifically when `PROMPT_COMMAND` is being evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned `$!` will contain the exit code of the last command when `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed. Matei David had a good suggestion to run `set` from the `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which reveals there's nothing (on my system) being added to the environment:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="set > /tmp/prompt.log"

$ set > /tmp/basic.log

$ diff -u0 /tmp/basic.log /tmp/prompt.log 
# no results
```

Of course this is anecdotal and doesn't include any Bash magic variables or other state not included by `set`, but it's a start.

You can get the last command with:

```
last_command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT='' history 1 | sed 's/ *[0-9]* *//')
```